# JMeter - Generate Parent Sample Default

Tags: testing, jmeter, default, parent, sample

When I record something in JMeter or create something in JMeter I always check the "Generate Parent Sample" checkbox. Is there a way I can enable this by default? I tried looking through the properties files but I could find nothing regarding this setting.

Kind regards,
Blacksoil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no property to do this.

You could try to ask on dev mailing list of JMeter if a property could be added for this but I am not sure it will be done.

Another option is to edit the XML file and make a find / replace after recording.